# Как настроить gulp и webpack?

Tags: gulp, webpack, webpack-stream

Хочу настроить gulp таким образом, чтобы он следил за файлами вместо webpack. При изменении файлов:

1. Мои JS-модули собирались в `app.js`
2. Вендорские JS-модули, импортированные из `/node_modules/` собирались в `vendor.min.js`
3. Вендорские стили, импортированные из `/node_modules/` собирались в `vendor.min.css`

Так вообще можно сделать через [webpack-stream](https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream)?

Comment: https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/watch

Comment: @StrangerintheQ и что? Где там хотя бы одно слово про webpack?

Comment: какая разница какая таска будет запускаться вотчером?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ мне больше нужен конфиг webpack, чем конфиг gulp. Gulp в вопросе нужен для понимания того, в каком контексте будет запускаться бандлер.

Comment: Я понял, сейчас поищу похожий конфиг, я раньше пользовался такой связкой...